# Spring Security: method is not secured with @PreAuthorize annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, roles, authorize

I would like to secure method in my managed session bean for specific role `"ROLE_ADMIN"`

config(applicationContext-security.xml):

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()"/>
        <form-login
         login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
         login-page="/login.jsf"
         default-target-url="/main.jsf"
         authentication-failure-url="/login.jsf" />

    <session-management>
           <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </session-management>
    </http>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="user1" password="user1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener"/>
```

bean's secured method:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String buy() {
...
    }
```

When I logged in under `user1` or as `anonym` and click "buy" button on web-page, it still redirected to the next page.

I expect that some access denied exception occurred, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember to enable method level security on your applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

If, insted you will use Pre or Post annotations, use:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

For more on this, see:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=77862

Note: For annotations from jsr-250:

```
<sec:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
```

Comment: actually tried,it's the same.As I understand,secured-annotations stands e.g. for @Secured annotation,that I don't use at all.I use pre post annotation @PreAuthorize

Comment: @sergionni: Sory, I'will edit to let you a more complete answer.

Comment: @logui, ok),np.I'm analyzing my config,perhaps it's intercept-url issue, i don't know yet

Comment: maven problem discovered by your link, i don't use maven at all

Comment: @sergionni: are you sure you have a pre-post-annotations enabled on your configuration and the exception is not been throwed? How are you handling such exceptions?

Comment: @sergionni: And even more Important... is the class where you have the annotated method managed as a bean by spring (e.g: with @Service annotation)?

Comment: @sergionni: Hummm... I don't think so... think we've got your error... and I think we have to take a look at spring and jsf integration specifics but I'm sure you will have to make a bean spring managed to be able to use spring security method-level annotations

Comment: @logui, looks like its really spring and jsf integration issue, i will open new thread

Comment: @sergionni ok, but when You find your answer do link the other thread here so If someone else come here looking for the same problem they will have a better picture of the solution

Comment: @Jonathas i didi like that `<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

   <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <authentication-provider>
      <password-encoder ref="encoder">
      </password-encoder>
         <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>`

Comment: @sergionni Thanks for the quick answer. My problem is that I'm using JSF and I can't get Spring Security with managed beans working together.